# error C2719: '_Val': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned?

Tags: c++, vector, directx, matrix, alignment

I'm trying to create a vector for `D3DXMATRIXA16` like so: `vector<D3DXMATRIXA16> matrices;` and am getting the error:

> ```
>      d:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\vector(717) :
> ```
>
> error C2719: '_Val': formal  parameter
>   with __declspec(align('16')) won't be
>   aligned
>
> ```
>     e:\projects\emuntitled\em\emscratch\emshadow.h(60) :
> ```
>
> :see reference to class template
>   instantiation 'std::vector<_Ty>' being
>   compiled
>           with
>           [
>               _Ty=D3DXMATRIXA16
>           ]

Why is that exactly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post the code where you use it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is a [known issue](http://ompf.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=686&start=0) [link dead] that stl::vector cannot properly contain aligned data, such as D3DXMATRIXA16.  One poster pinned the root cause (or at least, one of them?): the declaration of vector::resize passes the aligned data by value, and not as const reference. 
Several workarounds were suggested in that thread, the safest being *dropping stl::vector altogether*. You might also want to fix the stl headers yourself and recompile - this actually may be easier than it sounds, but I haven't done so myself.

EDIT: links are now broken (thanks @David Menard), here's [an alternative, more elaborate answer](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/stdvector-of-aligned-elements/).

The issue is fixed in VS2012RC - here's a link to [a corresponding connect issue](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/692988) [link dead]. Turns out it was actually an issue in the C++ standard itself, fixed in 2008.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the std::vector class requires the template parameter to be align(1); likely for some sort of fast indexing.