# Need a map but only need to know if contained?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate structure for my needs.

I need to have a dictionary or strings (words). All I need to know is if a given word is in the dictionary.

It seems like a waste of memory to make a map of string,string. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: should you eventually have a string-string dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `std::set<string>`. You can use `std::set::find` to check whether a word exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a `std::set< std::string >`.

Answer (score 0):

Naveen and K-ballo's answers are right. Here's something that might help you while choosing the right STL container for your needs. Note: This does not take into account C++11 types, but  it will help you get started with the STL: [image]

Comment: Shameless plug: the question was asked to redraw this diagram for C++11. I proposed a text alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11/10701102#10701102

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `std::set` is `std::unordered_set`. The first is typically implemented as a red-black tree (logarithmic complexity) and the second is a hash table (average constant-time complexity). `unordered_set` is available in C++11, C++03 TR1, and Boost.