# C++ : suitable Data Structure for this given scenario

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to know which data structure will be good in my case.Please guide me. Following are the requirements. As shown in the fig below, on the basis of three values A, B and C ( where A will be an integer value and B , C will be characters). The left side table will all have unique entries. I want to store two values accepting rule number and true/false.Thus, for each unique value of A,B and C I want to store two values (accepting rule number and true/false) corresponding to them.One important thing is that accepting rule number can be one or more (size is not fixed). Secondly, table length can go upto 65025 or above.

[image]

P.S: I asked this type of question previously but this time the scenario is little different.

Comment: And what are the criteria?

Comment: How would you like to retrieve the values

Comment: I don't really understand the relationship between the left table and the right table.

Comment: Is your (true/false) column the same as `!accepting_rules.empty()` ?

Comment: @Cyber: Apparently he has a number of rules (functions) mapping `(int, char, char) -> bool`, and needs to know for each entry what functions returned true.

Comment: @Cyber I think they're trying to demonstrate how they would access it. They want to map from the things on the left to the things on the right.

Comment: If the rules aren't expensive to evaluate, I wouldn't store the results at all.  Just have a function to return the vector of matching rules, given any input.

Comment: @JerryCoffin yes, you are right. accepting rule number can be more than one. Do i need to use link list in this case?

Comment: @Zara what you try to achieve

Comment: By what are the criteria, we mean that data structure choice is dependent on several factors, some of which you outline here (expected size, shape of data to be stored), some of which you do not (what are you optimizing for?  Insertion speed? Lookup speed? Deletion? Memory usage?)

This is why there are different data structures.  Otherwise, the answer would always be the same.

Comment: @JohnMcG Insertion speed, look up speed and memory usage are all important in my case.

Comment: You probably want a vector rather than a linked list. The real point is that this should typically have no effect on your decision about the overall data structure, so nothing relevant has changed from your previous question.

Comment: @Zara I think you should explain what task you want to do. I looked at your previous question.imho, What you need is just to & (and) rules to get final based on previous question

Comment: @qwr for each unique value from left table, I want to find out which rules are accepted if that unique value gets matched and then there is bool corresponding to that unique value. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us checks our basics, would you.

You basically want an association between a triplet (number, character, character) and a pair composed of two elements: a set of accepting rule numbers and a boolean (note: in your example the boolean is correlated with the fact that there is an accepting rule number or not).

So, we take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11/10701102#10701102) on how to best select a standard library container and follow its questions dumbly:

1. Associative ? Yes

   1. Ordered ? No => `unordered_`
   2. Separate Key ? Yes => `map`
   3. Multiple values ? No (single structure) => no `multi`

And that's it, you want an [`unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) from your key (the triplet) to your value (the pair).

For an unordered map, we need 5 template parameters:

- `Key` (the key)
- `T` (the value)
- `Hash`: a predicate that computes the hash of the key, it defaults to `std::hash<Key>` if correctly implemented
- `Equal`: a comparator that checks the idempotence of two keys with the same hash, since hashing is not injective, it defaults to `std::equal<Key>` (that is, to using `operator==`)
- `Allocator`: a memory allocator from where the container draws its memory, it defaults to `std::allocator`

So, providing that our `Key` can be hashed and compared for equality, we only really need to provide a `Key` and the associated value. Few keys are hashable though, so we'll provide the hasher ourselves.

```
struct TableKey {
    int A;
    char B;
    char C;
};

struct TableKeyHasher {
    size_t operator()(TableKey const& tk) const {
        return hash<int>(tk.A) ^ hash<char>(tk.B) ^ hash<char>(tk.C);
    }
};

bool operator==(TableKey const& left, TableKey const& right) {
    return std::tie(left.A, left.B, left.C) == std::tie(right.A, right.B, right.C);
}

bool operator!=(TableKey const& left, TableKey const& right) {
    return not (left == right);
}

struct TableValue {
    std::unordered_set<int> acceptingRules;
    bool someBooleanWithoutName;
};
```

And finally:

```
using MySuperTable = std::unordered_map<TableKey, TableValue, TableKeyHasher>;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and providing me the link. One thing I would like to ask since speed is important in my case. So, when I implemented previously unordered_map, it was taking lots of time  in map creation. Though, look up speed was fast but map creation time was extremely slow. Still I should go for unordered_map?

Comment: @Zara: unfortunately filling the map/table is effectively likely to be slow. However if this is only done during initialization (once) then the cost should be offset by fast look-up. If you want faster creation, you will have to think of friendlier memory structures (like arrays) however this will probably require a deeper investment on your part. In the extreme case, if the table is known ahead of time, you could use only arrays and build the table at compile-time directly into the executable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 struct Left{

int A;
char B, C;
int AcceptingIndex; //index of accepting number in the main array

};
```

}

```
struct Data{

int *PToAcceptNumber[size];
bool TF[size];

Left LeftValues[leftsize];


};
```

You have an array of arrays PToAcceptNumber. You could choose linked lists if you want, that would be an array of linked-lists. The left side values are in a struct Left. Each Left knows its accept values it identifies it by its index in the main array. Then each accept number list has a corresponding boolean value in the TF array.

Comment: Yes. The values A,B,C of the left table form a key for your table on the right. So whatever datastructure you are using, it will depend on that combined key. This also means iterating over the keys every time you want to look up the table no matter what values are used, so a hash - function could be usefull which's return value is used as a key for the struct Data. moved to anser section

Answer (score 1):

As much as I understood, this is how I would solve the problem:

B and C kept in a char matrix while A can simply be the counter you use for the lines of your matrix. Make a structure where in an int array of decent size ([10] for example), you should keep the rule numbers, and an unsigned variable that will keep the true or false 1 or 0. Define an array that will have the type of that structure and as manny elements as there are lines in that matrix. So in the end for every line in the char matrix you will have a structure that will contain the rules and the 1 or zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The values A,B,C of the left table form a key for your table on the right. So whatever datastructure you are using, it will depend on that combined key. This also means iterating over the keys every time you want to look up the table no matter what values are used, so a hash - function could be usefull which's return value is used as a key for the struct Data

Answer (score 1):

You question is vague, since you didn't tell us what operations you wish to support.

If your only purpose is retrieving an entry from the right table, given by an entry from the left table, then hash table is a good option, where you need to define two structs for both right table entry and left table entry.

Alternatively, you can also consider TRIE, which builds the left table as a prefix tree. This may help you save some space.

Moreover, if the right table is very sparse, e.g., too many 0-0 entries, you should consider store them as the pointers which point just one instance.

BTW, do you need to support any query based on the right table or any sorting function?