# C++, 2D std::vector, do I need to explicitly reserve and push back empty vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

When I make a 2D vector.

`std::vector<std::vector<Pokemon>> pokemons;`

Can I run this straight away:

`Pokemon pikachu = ...
pokemons[23].push_back(Pikachu);`

Or do I need to:

`pokemons.reserve(100);
for (int i =0;i<100;i++) pokemons.push_back(vector<Pokemon>());`

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can set the initial size of the outer vector during construction

```
std::vector<std::vector<Pokemon>> pokemons(100);
```

and it will build 100 inner empty vectors.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I do it if I already declared it?

For example:
`std::vector<std::vector<Pokemon>> pokemons;` is already set somewhere else in the code.

Comment: The vector has a `resize` function you can use to give it a new size, both bigger and smaller than the current size. You can check the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for lots of C++ reference info.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run this straight away:
>
> ```
> Pokemon pikachu = ...
> pokemons[23].push_back(Pikachu);
> ```

Not straight away, because your `pokemons` array does not have any elements yet, so `pokemons[23]` will be an out-of-bounds error.

Otherwise, once your `pokemons` array is populated, then yes, you can just `push_back` on one of its elements.

> Or do I need to:
>
> ```
> pokemons.reserve(100);
> for (int i =0;i<100;i++) pokemons.push_back(vector<Pokemon>());
> ```

`reserve()` is only to allocate (reserve) memory for your vector, if you have a good idea of how many elements you will end up having, to avoid multiple memory allocations and potential moves.  You do not *need* to `reserve()`, but it is a good idea if you will need a decent amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the vector is the most appropriate container you are looking for?
 Check [How can I efficiently select a Standard Library container in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699265/how-can-i-efficiently-select-a-standard-library-container-in-c11)

If '23' is really important, then you could for example use associative container:

```
 typedef std::map<int, pokemon> TPokemons;
 TPokemons pokemons;
 pokemons[23] = pikachu;
```

Maybe the order is not important and an [unordered map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) would be better