# How can I initialize an array in C++ with a size that is given to the constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, stdvector

I have a C++ class with a member that is supposed to be a two dimensional array. I want to declare my array as a member in the header file of the class. Then in the constructor of my class I want to initialize my array with a size (given to the constructor) and fill it with zeros.

I have a working example of what I want in java:

```java
class Obj {
    int[][] array;
    public Obj(int sizex, int sizey) {
        array = new int[sizex][sizey];
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Obj o = new Obj(12,20);
    }
}
```

I do not want to mess with pointers or alloc() and free(). As my class is supposed to be basically a wrapper for this array, I want to keep it simple.

I have thought about using std::vector, but as the array is never being resized after its initialization, I feel like vector is a little overpowered... Is there a better way than this: ?

```cpp
#include<vector>

class Obj {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> array;
    public:
    Obj(int xsize, int ysize) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int>> newArray(xsize, std::vector<int>(ysize, 0));
        array = newArray;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Obj o(12,20);
}
```

Comment: Why would a `std::vector` be "overpowered" for this? You could create dynamically allocated arrays manually, but then you need to also correctly keep track of their size. Either way it would be roughly the same result

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711697/is-there-any-use-for-unique-ptr-with-array/16711846. Though, I am not sure how well that works for 2d

Comment: @UnholySheep Because I am only going to access it via `array[index]` and never use push, pop, the iterators or any other fancy stuff.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number The linked post literally says "Don't use it." xD

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl I dont see where you found that. The accepted answer states: "you use unique_ptr<T[]> when you need to". Requireing to forbid resizing is what makes you need something different from a vector

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new
See if this helps

Comment: Are the dimensions known at compiletime?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No. There are going to be multiple Objects with different sized arrays.

Comment: @TorgeRosendahl Ok, but still, are the sizes of those objects known at compiletime?

Comment: @TedLyngmo No they are not.

Comment: Note that for a 2-dimensional grid like this using a 1-dimensional array is usually a better solution, see how to do so in e.g.: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212808/treating-a-1d-data-structure-as-2d-grid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::vector` is the best match here. (As you said, in most cases raw arrays and pointers could be avoided. Also see [How can I efficiently select a Standard Library container in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10699265/3309790))

And you can initialize the data member directly in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) instead of assigning in the constructor body after default-initialization, e.g.

```
Obj(int xsize, int ysize) : array(xsize, std::vector<int>(ysize, 0)) {
}
```

Comment: Yeah I should have thought about the initializer list. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Other than using std::vector you can just allocate memory of the required size from the heap.

```
class Obj {
    int** arr;
    int x, y;
public:
    Obj(int sizex, int sizey) : x(sizex), y(sizey) {
        arr = new int*[sizex];
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizex; i++) {
            arr[i] = new int[sizey];
        }
    }

    //IMPORTANT TO DELETE, OTHERWISE YOU'LL GET A MEMORY LEAK
    ~Obj() {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            delete[] arr[i];
        }
        delete[] arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Though you might wanna use smart pointers (simple google search will do) instead of raw pointers so you don't have to bother with deallocating the memory.

Comment: And with smart pointer, rule of 5/3/0 is respected, contrary to your example, copy/move constructor/assignment are missing.