# Array or vector declaration for aligned datatype Eigen::Matrix

Tags: c++, arrays, std, eigen

I have an class `ClusterNode` which contains an `Eigen::Matrix4d` as a class variable. I also have a function `numNodes()` which tells me the total number of `ClusterNode`s, so that I can collect them in some sort of array, list, or vector.

However, `Eigen::Matrix4d` is aligned which means I cannot store objects of this type in a `std::vector<ClusterNode>` as per the answer to this question [error C2719: '_Val': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281415/error-c2719-val-formal-parameter-with-declspecalign16-wont-be-alig)

As an alternative, I have tried using an array.

However, I cannot do

```
const int n = numNodes();
ClusterNode array [n];
```

Because the return value of a function is not considered a constant.

What other options do I have?

Comment: `ClusterNode* array = new ClusterNode[n];`

Comment: Did you read the answer in that linked question?  `std::vector` no longer passes the element type by value, so non-overalignment of function parameters is no longer an issue.

Comment: @Ben I must have an older compiler version, because I still get the compiler error.

Comment: What is your compiler version?

Comment: @Ben Visual C++ 10, the fix was added in Visual C++ 11

Comment: @Alex, I used your solution. So simple, but I was stuck on the idea of avoiding 'new'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Eigen's aligned_allocator. See [this page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) for the details, but basically you can do:

```
std::vector<ClusterNode, Eigen::aligned_allocator<ClusterNode> >
```

Also don't forget to overload operator new for your class. Again, all the details are in the Eigen's [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStructHavingEigenMembers.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use memalign or posix_memalign to allocate and align a variable memory space

http://man.he.net/man3/memalign

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Alex Faber's solution

```
ClusterNode* array = new ClusterNode[n];
```

But I wanted to add the note that, in this case, **the class also needs to return alligned pointers**. It will only cause problems part of the time, in a very annoying and untracable way, but after much bug hunting, I finally got a useful error message that pointed me to [Eigen's documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html).

A summary of the documentation: Eigen needs 16-byte aligned memory. The following cases will lead to grief.

1. std containers containing Eigen types
2. classes or structures containing Eigen types
3. passing Eigen types to functions by value
4. gcc on Windows has wrong alignment (4-byte)

If I use the dynamic array solution proposed by Alex (ClusterNode as a variable at all for that matter), I also need to use a macro provided by Eigen to ensure that the objects are aligned. For example,

```
class ClusterNode
{
    Eigen::Matrix4d M;

public:
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
}
```

If the macro is not included, the array declaration will sometimes silently fail.